# How do I add a comma after the fourth character in a sentence?

Tags: c#

I know nothing of C# so I'm hoping somebody here can help. So my question is how would I add a "," after the fourth character in a string. Something like:

**Hell,o?**

Comment: -1, knowing nothing doesn't mean you can't invest 30 seconds to check on google first..

Comment: I actually did google it first but couldn't figure it out :(

See: http://imgur.com/6Xasg

Comment: Try this on Google ... "C# insert comma into string"

Comment: nice query :)) "add a coma after 4 characters c#" doesn't give you a good chance to find anything, you need to generalize a bit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.Insert()`:

```
string test = "Hello";
test = test.Insert(4, ",");
```

You should check if the string is long enough though like so:

```
if (test.Length > 4) {
     test = test.Insert(4, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) and give the number 4 as parameter (since the first char is on place 0)

```
string s = "hello";
s = s.Insert(4, ",");
```

Comment: He doesn't necessarilly **need** to use Insert, also the correct parameter value is 4, since he wants to insert **after** 4th character

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx).

E.g. `myString.Insert(4, ",");`

Answer (score 0):

String.Insert is the answer:

```
string test1 = "Hello";
string test2 = test1.Insert(4, ",");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx

Answer (score 0):

var str ="Hello";

var finalString = string.Format("{0},{1}",str.Substring(0,4),str.Substring(4));

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, strings are immutable so you have to create a new string

```
var sampleString = "Testing";

var resultString = sampleString.Insert(3, ",);
```

resultString is "Test,ing"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
        String str = "Hello";
        str = str.Substring(0, 4) + "," + str.Substring(4, str.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna Propose an alternative to insert, this way it'll be possible for future users to use for editing a longer string and put in values at different intervals eg.

"hello my name is Anders"
becomes
"hell,o my, nam,e is, And,ers"

A string in C# is basically an array of chars, so you could loop through it and when you reach the fourth loop you could insert your ,

something like this

```
string hello="hello";
string newvar ="";
foreach(int i =0;i<hello.length;i++)
{
    if(i==4)
    newvar+=",";
    newvar+=hello[i];
}
```

if you want it to be each fourth space you can check if 0%=4/i

you can also use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) split it up into multiple pieces put in your "," and put it back together, I suggest you take a look at the documentation for the string class at Microsofts homepage